# jenkins java.io.FileNotFoundException: .. (No such file or directory)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I can execute the below script successfully with groovy locally but the same script when executed in Jenkins returns the error message
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/Leo_JF_sw_daily_integration_model_pytest/jenkinsfile/case_config/santity_check.txt (No such file or directory)`

What went wrong here?

**Script**

```
    case_list = ""
    new File("${WORKSPACE}/jenkinsfile/case_config/${test_set.case_config}").eachLine {
    line ->    case_list = line + "," + case_list; }
    println(case_list)
```

The file exists and has the proper Permissions.

So, I tried with the below script, but it also failed in Jenkins

```
String fileContents = new File("${WORKSPACE}/jenkinsfile/case_config/${test_set.case_config}").text
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `new File` you should use [readFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) from Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @MaratC, "readFile" worked for me.                                                                  String case_list = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/jenkinsfile/case_config/${test_set.case_config}"